# ZenDesk API result does not match call when deleting

Tags: php, zendesk

I am using the ZenDesk API (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/introduction) to synchronise a ZenDesk setup with another client database. When I try to delete an organization, I get a response that seems to suggest an update call has been made.

According to the documentation (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/organizations#delete-organization) the call should be DELETE /api/v2/organizations/{id}.json where the {id} is the id of the organization.

I have written code that I believe to be correct, and checked this with Fiddler. The call comes through on Fiddler as:

```
DELETE /api/v2/organizations/39005971.json HTTP/1.1
```

The raw request view shows (with redactions):

```
DELETE https://<redacted>.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/39005971.json HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic <redacted>
Host: <redacted>.zendesk.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
```

and the response comes back as:

```
{
    "error":"RecordInvalid",
    "description":"Record validation errors",
    "details":{
        "name":[
            {
                "description":"Name: has already been taken",
                "error":"DuplicateValue"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the same response that is given if you try to insert an organization with the same name as an existing one. From the documentation, the basic difference between deleting and updating a record is that delete requests use DELETE and updates use PUT - the endpoint URL is the same.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I can provide upstream code (in PHP) if needed, however as Fiddler is picking up the request as a correctly formatted DELETE, I'm not sure that the code is going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually work for Zendesk and figured this out personally. You seemed to have run into a bug having to do with the max characters an organization name can have. You probably had a couple organizations whose names were more than 255 characters long and after getting truncated to 255 were the same name. Now validation issues are popping up. I'm really sorry about that!

I would send a request to https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and we'll fix this issue for you!

Comment: Thanks Victor! I have done that, and will mark this question as solved if the diagnosis proves correct!

Comment: ZenDesk have acknowledged that this is a glitch in their API and it's been escalated to the engineering team. Thanks to Victor and others at ZenDesk for their helpful responses.

Comment: For completeness - a fix for the issue has now been pushed, so the bug is now dead.